# Session expires in embedded IWebBrowser2 upon opening another embedded IWebBrowser2 for NewWindow3 handling

Tags: session, popup, iwebbrowser2

I am working on a multi-threaded WTL-based application that opens multiple browser windows, each with its own embedded IWebBrowser2 instance for the browsing, and each in a separate UI thread.

In response to NewWindow3, I open a new browser-window, and return the new window's `IWebBrowser2->get_Application()` which returns an `IDispatchPtr`.

While the popup does open the desired site, the session in the original window, from which this popup was opened, EXPIRES - any further navigation in that original window takes be back to the login page!

Some points that I thought may be important for anyone to help me -

1. This happens ONLY when the `NewWindow3` is fired, with a non-empty `bstrUrlContext` (the 3rd parameter containing the originating URL)
2. As part of the NewWindow3 processing, the following done -

   - Creation of the new IWebBrowser2-embedding window, `Create()`'ed with `zWindowName` set to the value of the `bstrUrlContext` parameter
   - The returned `IDispatch` pointer is retrieved from `IWebBrowser2->get_Application()`

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.

I had to create the IWebBrowser2-embedding window with an empty-string (_T("")) WindowName.
And had to ensure creation of the IWebBrowser2 control by invoking CAxWindow::CreateControl() in the window's OnCreate() handler (for WM_CREATE)

Thanks